# HTML/CSS span popup display not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a Chrome extension that, when hovering over a `p`, `h1`, etc, will display a popup with that element's `font-family`. It works for the most part, but doesn't display correctly sometimes, as shown in pictures below.

How can I set up the CSS styles such that it will position itself absolutely and will always expand to fit the text AND be fully visible? The extension works by using `appendChild` to add a span containing the hidden popup to the current element.

[image]
[image]

Notice how in the second picture,the popup is cut off because of the constraints of its parent.

CSS:

```
.crx_mouse_visited:hover .popup {
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width : 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: Post an [mcve], not two CSS rules

Comment: @j08691 That is the entirety of the CSS right there. The images show the .popup class. What else would you like me to provide?

Comment: Are you appending this *`<span class="popup">`* at the end of the *DOM* like where body ends? or just within that *`hovered`* element?

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
.crx_mouse_visited:hover .popup {
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```